# reduce response time of an api call in springboot webflux project

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

i am working on a springboot project. i have an api which takes around 7-8 secs for response. i want to reduce it to less than a sec.
please find below the code :

CONTROLLER:

```
 @GetMapping("/agent/V2")
    public Flux<TaskMinimizedDtoForAgent> findAllTaskByAgentIdV2(@RequestParam UUID agentId) {
        return agentService.findAllTaskByAgentIdV2WithStatus(agentId);
    }
```

SERVICE:

```
public Flux<TaskMinimizedDtoForAgent> findAllTaskByAgentIdV2WithStatus(UUID agentId) {

    return findAllTaskByAgentIdV2(agentId)
            .flatMap(taskMinimizedDto -> updateTaskAndProcessWithStatus(agentId, taskMinimizedDto));
}

private Mono<TaskMinimizedDtoForAgent> updateTaskAndProcessWithStatus(UUID agentId, TaskMinimizedDtoForAgent taskMinimizedDto) {
    return processService.getOverallStatusForAgentForProcesses(agentId)
            .flatMap(processStatusMap -> {
                // Update process status in TaskMinimizedDtoForAgent if corresponding processId exists
                taskMinimizedDto.getProcesses().forEach(processDto -> {
                    String processId = processDto.getId().toString();
                    if (processStatusMap.containsKey(processId)) {
                        // Set the status from the second method
                        processDto.setStatus(processStatusMap.get(processId));
                    }
                });

                // Update the overall task status
                return processService.getCombinedStatusForAgentForATask(agentId, taskMinimizedDto.getId())
                        .map(overallStatusForTask -> {
                            taskMinimizedDto.setStatus(overallStatusForTask);
                            return taskMinimizedDto;
                        });
            });
}
```

THE code in service layer needs to be optimized to reduce response time.

i tried to reduce response time by using parallel processing as below:

```
private Mono<TaskMinimizedDtoForAgent> updateTaskAndProcessWithStatus(UUID agentId, TaskMinimizedDtoForAgent taskMinimizedDto) {
    Mono<Map<String, StatusEnum>> overallStatusMono = processService.getOverallStatusForAgentForProcesses(agentId)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel());

    Mono<StatusEnum> combinedStatusMono = processService.getCombinedStatusForAgentForATask(agentId, taskMinimizedDto.getId())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel());

    return Mono.zip(overallStatusMono, combinedStatusMono)
            .flatMap(tuple -> {
                Map<String, StatusEnum> processStatusMap = tuple.getT1();

                // Update process status in TaskMinimizedDtoForAgent if corresponding processId exists
                taskMinimizedDto.getProcesses().forEach(processDto -> {
                    String processId = processDto.getId().toString();
                    if (processStatusMap.containsKey(processId)) {
                        // Set the status from the first method
                        processDto.setStatus(processStatusMap.get(processId));
                    }
                });

                // Update the overall task status
                StatusEnum overallStatusForTask = tuple.getT2();
                taskMinimizedDto.setStatus(overallStatusForTask);

                return Mono.just(taskMinimizedDto);
            });
}
```

but the response time is almost same.  is there a better way to optimize ?

Comment: Instead of randomly modify the code, measure. Measure what is slow and figure out how to make that faster. You might not even be able to make it as fast as you want.